# What does *to see no other choice* mean, really?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

The phrase to *see no other choice* is used in contexts I don't quite understand.  Some snippets from Google Search:

[Soldiers in Cities](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ShqXFdkh5sMC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22see+no+other+choice%22&source=bl&ots=nIfryZLbkh&sig=dDwlTl8fhi_6cm6MOnR_JGBcu94&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix9I7GouHNAhWhDMAKHQzjDZA4ChDoAQg0MAc#v=onepage&q=%22see%20no%20other%20choice%22&f=false):

> ... forces are ever engaged in high-intensity urban warfare, it is almost certainly going to be because the political and military leadership see no other choice

[A meme on suicide](https://whisper.sh/whisper/0517b09032640a45773851cb45fe3d5a5e91ed/People-kill-themselves-because-they-see-no-other-choice-they-get-trappe):

> People kill themselves because they see no other choice

[Waves of Rancor: Tuning in on the Radical Right](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y5In7xScVbwC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22see+no+other+choice%22&source=bl&ots=361pEhlpPr&sig=qrXrrAdzkXqNxNMy4XNzO57CYsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix9I7GouHNAhWhDMAKHQzjDZA4ChDoAQhGMA0#v=onepage&q=%22see%20no%20other%20choice%22&f=false):

> While many in the hard to the ultra-right as well as the moderate right, vote Republican, it is because they see no other choice.

Literally speaking, there is always another choice.  So clearly, the meaning is not literal.  What does *to see no other choice* mean, really?

Comment: If there is another choice, they do not see it as viable, or they simply are blind to it for some other reason. An alternative does not occur to them. In some cultures, seeking personal vengeance, for example, is an honor-bound duty. Allowing the law to handle the situation, or forgiveness, are not even considered.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understand the literal meaning of the words well enough; the question is just the idiomatic meaning.  *To see no other choice* is used idiomatically to mean "to perceive there to be no other *reasonable* choice" or "to perceive that there is no other choice *that is any better than this one*."

For example, in your last sentence,

> While many in the hard to the ultra-right as well as the moderate right, vote Republican, it is because they see no other choice.

the people who vote Republican obviously technically have other choices: they could stay home and not vote, or vote for a third party candidate.  But idiomatically what's meant is that they perceive no other reasonable option, because they see voting Republican as the least bad option, or the only one that has any chance of getting them what they want.

In your example about suicide, the people obviously have the choice to not commit suicide, but when we say they see no other choice, we mean that they feel that every other option is less tolerable than suicide.